# Paralist package breaks hyperref pdf links

Tags: hyperref, pdf, paralist

Something bizarre is happening with the clickable links that `hyperref` creates in my PDF file.  Here is an example LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,paralist}
\usepackage[dvipdfm, bookmarks, bookmarksdepth=2]{hyperref}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem} \label{thm:test}
\begin{enumerate}[\rm (a)]
\item First thing.
\item Second thing.
\item Third thing.
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

Reference to Theorem~\ref{thm:test}(a).

\end{document}
```

It compiles without warnings (using LaTeX), but when I then convert the DVI file to a PDF file with `dvipdfm` I get

```
** WARNING ** PDF destination "theorem.0.1" not defined.
```

I can open the PDF file, but the clickable link for the theorem just doesn't do anything.

The problem seems to be the `paralist` package : if you remove it, then everything works just fine.  Also, if you insert a line of text between the `\begin{theorem}` and the `\begin{enumerate}` lines, then it also works fine.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @egreg : Hmm, that doesn't explain the apparent role of paralist.

Comment: Use `enumitem` instead of `paralist`

Comment: The problem is with the driver: whan I compile with `pdflatex` it works fine.

Comment: The problem is not dependent on `paralist` (or `enumitem`). It can be seen with `latex+dvipdfmx` or `pdflatex` (removing the `dvipdfm` option) and also with `latex+dvips+ps2pdf`. In this last case no message is shown, but the link doesn't work. In all cases, adding what's suggested in Heiko Oberdiek's answer to the linked question solves the issue.